# new keystore to update an android app

Tags: android, cordova, keystore

Some days ago I've uploaded a Cordova android app to Google Play Store.
I generated the Keystore through `keytool` and then manually signed with `Jarsigner`. The app is on Google Play App Signing Program.

Unfortunately, I lost the Keystore file (I accidentally replaced the original Keystore file with a new one) and now I can't upload an update for the app because the signature doesn't correspond.

According to this [this support article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), because my app is in the Google Play App Signing, I can ask Google to change the Keystore file, but It is not really clear for me how to proceed.
I just have to generate a new keystore file with:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore new.keystore -alias <app-alias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And then use the command indicated in the article:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias <app-alias> -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore new.keystore
```

to export the new certificate `upload_certificate.pem` and send it to Google Support?

In this process, the certificates in "App Signing" page of the Google Developer Console are not involved at all. Is it correct?

After this process, I can just sign the app with the new Keystore and then upload the updates?

Thank in advance, and yes I know that Keystore files must be backed up (or at least now I know).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact google [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs).
Generate a new certificate and attached the certificate for the new key of PEM format.

Note that you must contact Google from the same console account used to upload the previous app and key to playstore.